# Strategies for "I, Zombie Endless"

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

What are some good strategies for the "I, Zombie Endless" modes in Plants vs. Zombies?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Though I haven't played in a while, here are some pointers I can think of:

1. Remember how much hits each zombie can survive. This takes some trial and error, but once you get the feel you can make wiser decisions as to your zombie placements. An imp, for example, can walk over thorns and live (two hits, if I remember correctly), but the next hit will make him drop dead (again).
2. Maximize your use of the dancer zombie. This guy can save you a lot of sun if used correctly. Optimally, you can clear three lanes with minimal casualties by placing him in any non-extreme lane (not topmost nor bottommost). Of course, you would have to make sure to eliminate all ranged opposition in the lane you actually place him on and be wary of plants with split fire (such as the star fruit). You don't have to worry about squashes or chompers since they will waste themselves on the summoned zombie dancing directly in front of the dancer. I also remember that when first placed and performing his moonwalk, this zombie can simply bypass plants. Learn to use this to your advantage.
3. Sometimes placing two cheaper
   zombies can have the same effect as
   placing one stronger zombie (which
   costs more than both the cheaper
   ones). For instance, if you have a
   snow pea shooting at you from deep
   in a lane, two plain zombies might
   be able to reach it, alternating the
   shot damage between them as one
   thaws and the other doesn't.
4. Scaredy shrooms cower in fear even when a zombie approaches them on an adjacent lane (not only on their actual lane). Timing your zombie placement right, you can cash in on this behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Can't think up better page in internet to share my trick.</sub>

If:

1. there is a lane you are interested in only because of brain or 1-2 last sunflowers
2. it's protected too much for straight attack
3. but isn't protected much by shooting backwards
4. there is a one magnet, protecting this lane

then you can get brains with cost of 250, ignoring that strong lane defense:

1. send any metal zombie (bucket or miner) to deactivate the magnet
2. wait several seconds and send miner zombie there
3. the magnet drops item and takes the miner's pickaxe
4. the miner zombie gets out right between brain and dangerous flowers **and goes to the left!**

Of course, it's hard and rare to use, but is rather effective.

Comment: that's a neat trick

Answer (score 1):

- If there's a potato mine in the lane you want to put a zombie on, send a Bungee zombie to take care of it.
- When you have over 1000 sun, try a few ladder zombies. Remember, only one ladder is taken away.
- If you want to place a Ladder Zombie where a Fume-shroom is, try sending a Football zombie after it. You can have him protect your Ladder zombie as he eats the fume shroom.
- If you have Chomper issues,the Digger zombie isn't effected by them.
- If you need sun, bungee zombies stealing sunflowers also give you sun.

Answer (score 1):

I used this guide, which is quite complex and i can recommend it

http://www.download-free-games.com/blog/i-zombie-endless-guide

The key point is to think twice before sending a zombie and observer where the key plants are:

- magnet one with 2 fields area
- palm with 1 field area
- star - shooting 5 sides

Also you can try to use macro for getting some additional suns throught the bungee zombies e.g. as here

but its not neccessary